# JQuery + table issue with IE

Tags: jquery

I have a dynamic table with a delete button and several input elements on each row. Each row has an ID. When i push the delete button I use jQuery to delete the row and then update the ID's. Like this

```
function deleteRow(row) {
    var num = $("#table>tbody>tr").length;
    if (num > 1) {
        $(row).closest("tr").remove();
    }
    updateIds();
}

function updateIds() {
        var counter = 0;
        var num = $("#myTable>tbody>tr").length;
        $("#myTable>tbody>tr").each(function(){
            $("input",this).each(function(){
                var currentId = $(this).attr("id");
                var newId = currentId.substring(0,currentId.indexOf(('_'))+1);
                $(this).attr("id",newId+counter);
                var currentPath = $(this).attr("name");

                var front = currentPath.substring(0,currentPath.indexOf('[')+1);
                var back = currentPath.substring(currentPath.indexOf(']'));

                $(this).attr("name",front+counter+back);

            })

            counter++;
        })
    }
```

This works Fine in FF and Chrome but in IE 7 I am having some trubble after running these two functions. When i focus on an input element in a tr the cursor jumps up one row. Its like its trying to fucus on the tr that was just deleted.

Anybody have any ideas

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can manually set the focus with:

```
$(element).focus();
```

Get the element using the index of the row/cell you want the focus to be. Does that help?

Comment: Focus is not the problem, its when i have focus on the field and start typing the cursor jumps to identical field in the row on top